# Google Search Analytics is not working since 1 week ago

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

The last stats i have receipt in [Search Analytics](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics) is for 13 august and google does not report click stats for my [website](https://darooy.ir)

Also google does not index my new pages or new submitted sitemaps urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to John Mueller from Google: The Search Console has some serious issues with the Search Analytics Data at the moment. They say it should work normaly in a couple of days.

https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/898194378518388736

Answer (score 0):

I found myself some reports from google:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211453#search_analytics